# easydropdown.js removing options

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to remove select option based on on different selectbox option.
It's pretty straightforward when using standard select box, but in my case I went with fancy alternative easydropdown.js which converts select box to divs and spans.

Here: (if you select "Zanjo", "Urejen_gospod" should dissapear:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#segment').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'zanjo'){ 
          $("#interest option[value='urejen_gospod']").remove();
        }
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0zxxrmta/1/

Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `li` selector

is this you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/ry4unp1q/

Comment: I really have to get my hands on jquery. Thanks Sarath that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I have another problem ... I'm refreshing products with form: onchange="this.form.submit()" and in this case code no longer works...any idea why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ry4unp1q/1/  The thing is page is being refreshed and products are being listed when you select specific option.

Comment: are you submitting to the same page?

Comment: I'm submitting to different page but I'm calling header.php where this selectbox is located...

Comment: Since the page is submitted on any item click , the page will reset every time you pick an item and that's what happening here.. Tell me what you actually need

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly what your code does on jsfiddle. But when page is being refreshed after form is submitted select option doesn't get attribute "display:none", so I guess I could solve this with cookies? Or is there any easier way to keep class after page refresh?

Comment: You need the attribute to be display:none only if you previously selected 'zanjo' right?

Comment: Yes exactly. So after I select "Zanjo" "Urejen gospod" disappears.

Comment: Okay.. then i think its better to use ajax to submit the form instead of reloading the whole page. using ajax you can submit the form without refreshing the current page..

Comment: You can refer to a simple ajax example http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples

Comment: You can perform the ajax submit on the onchange event of the dropdown

Comment: YES :) For each category I have unique URL so I just remove whole li with 
if(window.location.href.indexOf("zanjo") > -1) {
     $( "li:contains('Urejen gospod')").remove();
    }

Thanks a lot for your effort!